# Is it possible to light a led bulb with AA battery?

Tags: led, batteries

Total novice to electrical engineering.

Is it possible to light a led bulb with AA battery?

What are the factors to consider here. For example resistance, consistent power supply, etc.

Why does a short circuit happen if a single led is plugged directly to wall socket?

Comment: Do you mean an LED, or do you mean a light bulb with LEDs in it?  LEDs aren't usually called "bulbs."

Comment: If you are doing what you suggest in paragraph 3 then you should not play with electricity.

Answer (score 6):

Read about a circuit called "Joule-Thief".

Single AA battery cannot light up an led. An AA battery has a nominal voltage of 1.5V which varies from 1.1 to 1.5 depending upon how much the battery has been discharged.

Most LEDs require 2.5 - 3.5V minimum to turn on. Reds LED turning on at the lower voltages while Blue LEDs require higher voltages.

Two AA batteries in series can light up an LED since they together supply about 3V. This should work for most LEDs except Blue and may be White. More cells in Series will surely work but then you need to add a resistor in series to limit the current.

There is one way with which you can use a single battery to light up an LED which is a Joule thief circuit. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_thief

It uses an oscillator to increase the voltage at the expense of a higher current draw.

Comment: This answer is a bit short for the standards of this site: Please explain, in words that nish will understand, what a "Joule-Thief" is, and how it applies to the question he's having!

Comment: You sadly still didn't quite explain what a Joule Thief does; it's not "just an oscillator"! (still the best answer here, so upvoted you!)

Comment: A single AA can light up an infrared LED without any boosting circuit!

Answer (score 6):

You cannot light a visible light LED with **just** a single AA cell.

A single AA cell provides about 1.5 volts.

A red LED requires about 1.8 volts to light up, and will not light at all at a lower voltage.

All other colors of visible light LEDs require a higher voltage, and so will not work on a single cell either.

Infrared LEDs light at around 1.5 volts, so it is possible to "light" an infrared LED with a single cell.  You won't see it because human eyes don't respond to infrared light.  It's not a good idea, anyway.  If any current flows at all, it won't be controlled in any way.  Too much current might then flow and destroy the infrared LED.

The typical, cheap way to light an LED is to use a battery of 2 cells in series.  Two AA cells will give you enough voltage for red, green, yellow, and orange LEDs.

Blue LEDs (and white LEDs, which are just blue LEDs in disguise) need three volts or more, and so will not work reliably from 2 AA cells in series.  You can use 3 AA cells for them, or 4 because three cell AA holders aren't very common.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LED_circuit) has a nice page on LED circuits.  It includes a suggested circuit and formula for calculating the value of the needed resistor.

Here's the circuit:

[image]

The circle thing marked "V" represents your battery.

The zig-zag thing marked "R" is a resistor.

The arrow shaped thing on the right represents the LED.

The resistor is used to limit the current through the LED.

To calculate the value of resistor you need, you need a few numbers:

- \$V_b\$ - the voltage of your battery.  2 AA cells in series deliver about 3V.
- \$V_L\$ - the forward voltage of the LED.  This varies with each color of LED. Red LEDs have a forward voltage of around 1.8V.
- \$I_L\$ - the current you want to flow through the LED. More current is brighter, but too much will destroy your LED. Most common LEDs have a safe maximum current of about 20 milliamperes (0.02 amperes.)

The formula you need to calculate the value of the resistor is this:

$$ R = \frac {V_b - V_L}{I_L}$$

A resistor of that value will limit the current through the LED to a safe value.

For the red LED and 2AA cells I mentioned above, it looks like this:

$$ R = \frac{3.0 - 1.8}{0.02}= 60$$

You need at least a 60 ohm resistor to safely operate a red LED from 2 AA cells in series.

It'll probably be far too bright, though.  You can safely use larger value resistors to dim a bright LED.  You'll probably have to try it out and see how high you need to make the resistor to dim the LED to your liking.  Just stay above the calculated value, and it will be OK.

---

The reason a simple LED shorts out and explodes when you connect it directly to a wall outlet is because LEDs are basically a short circuit to begin with.

Once the applied voltage goes above the forward voltage, LEDs conduct current.  They don't have any kind of limiting for how much current they will allow to flow.  More voltage = more current = brighter until it burns out.

With 110 volts (or 240 volts, depending on where you live) the LED will let through a lot of current and burn out instantly.

---

There is a way to make an LED light from a lower voltage, but you'll need a little more than just a AA cell and the LED.

You can use a voltage booster to convert the low voltage to a higher voltage.  You then use the higher voltage to light the LED.

The Joule thief circuit mentioned in other answers is a simple voltage booster.

A voltage booster uses an inductor to convert pulses of DC at a low voltage to pulses of DC at a higher voltage.

The oscillator circuits used to make a typical voltage booster operate automatically obscure the basic operating principle.

An inductor will always try to keep the current through itself constant.  Once you have current flowing through it, if you interrupt the flow then the inductor will try to keep the current flow by delivering current itself.  It will raise the voltage if necessary to keep the current flowing.

This is the circuit diagram of a very simple voltage booster I built:

[image]

The completed thing looks like this:

[image]

You rub the bare wire in the lower right corner across the rough surface of the file, and that acts like a switch that is turned on and off very quickly.

The result is a series of pulses of voltage high enough to light the LED.

If you replace the mechanical switch with a transistor and an oscillator, then you have a Joule thief that will drive an LED from a single AA cell.

I borrowed the schematic and photo from my [blog posts](https://josepheoff.github.io/posts/3-voltagebooster-toc) on building the simple voltage booster.

The blog posts go into more detail about the voltage booster and how it works.

Answer (score 2):

AA batteries may be used to light LEDs.

The factors to be considered are LED forward voltage, LED forward current and battery voltage.

The battery voltage should be higher than the LED forward voltage. A resistor is to be used in series to limit the LED current.

The resistor value is to be calculated using the formula

Battery voltage = LED forward voltage + (LED forward current * Resistor value).

The required resistor wattage is to be arrived at using the formula

Wattage = (LED forward current)² * Resistor value.

The LED blew since 120/240V was applied to it instead of 2V.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible. All you have to do is to make a mechanical inverter. Using a neodymium magnet sphere, a DC motor and a coil without core -  from an AC motor (example microwave turntable motor). You will lose amperage, but you will increase voltage enough to light a 7W AC bulb 230 V. The secret is to fix the neodymium sphere between the magnetic poles

[image: mechanical inverter]

These are 3 of my videos:

VIDEO 1 - AAA battery and 7W 230 V bulb https://youtu.be/dA5YncN1mak
Depending on sphere dimensions and coil and battery, you can create models of mechanical inverters.

VIDEO 2 - AA battery and 7W 230 V led bulb https://youtu.be/VVluvRR0E6c

VIDEO 3 - it is possible also for a 75 W bulb if you will use 2 x 3.7 V batteries https://youtu.be/Ud3fMcn7GAw

Formula : rotating magnetic fields generator + coil = AC voltage

On my YouTube channel you can see different tests with batteries and bulbs.

Answer (score -1):

Lithium button cell batteries (e.g. CR2032) are 3V and have internal resistance, so a single cell can light some LEDs without a resistor.

I found this question when researching how to power an LED bulb with a battery, e.g. a fancy LED flame flickering bulb that normally screws into an AC powered light socket. But I'm pretty sure that would also involve removing some extra circuitry in the bulb.

This LED has a flicker circuit inside and works without a resistor.

[image]

Comment: If you used a single 3V AA battery, or even two standard 1.5V AA batteries, it would burn out the red LED quite quickly with overcurrent. So there goes your plan of doing it without resistors. If that is supposed to be a red LED, it's already damaged and turning orange due to overheating and overcurrent, and is not fully burnt out due to CR2032 batteries having such a large internal resistance which limits current, and also CR2032 batteries are not rated for that high currents, so you are also misusing the battery.

Comment: No, it's a yellow LED. It comes from a cheap tealight sold on Amazon that is literally just a plastic case, the LED, a rubber flame tip covering the LED, the CR2032, and a power switch that simply pushes the LED's pin into contact with the battery (the other pin is in fixed contact with the other pole). This LED has some flickering effect so maybe it has internal resistance? Good to know about the CR2032's large internal resistance.

Comment: If it has a flicker IC inside, then it may have internal resistor, so it is not a regular LED, it is an exception. The answer still says you can connect a red LED to a 3V coin cell. While many things can be done, it does not mean it is recommended to do it, or is it better to not do it.